# Is the Gmail Webapp message count broken, or did I just do something wrong?

Tags: gmail

For whatever reason, the Gmail Webapp doesn't show a count or a notification that I have new mail. The ONLY time the envelope turns blue is when I'm already in gmail via Firefox. But as soon as I close the browser, even if I have unread mail, the icon turns back to white.

No counter either, which is confusing. I'm a noob when it comes to Ubuntu and linux in general, so I wouldn't know where to begin to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything wrong.

The Ubuntu Web App for Gmail is relatively new and just doesn't do much yet. It only works when Gmail is open in the web browser.